# Make JWT authentication (with refresh token) work efficiently with React+Redux?

Tags: reactjs, authentication, redux, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I'm using django rest framework with simplejwt in the backend and React with Redux and axios in the frontend.

The jwt authentication for the log-in and requests authentication is working well.

Now I am looking for a good way to use the refresh functionality from the frontend.
I'm not sure at what point of the redux workflow I should be triggering the check exipiry/refreh token so that the access token can be refreshed to let active users keep using the app. If both tokens are expired than the user should be automatically logged out.

Would really appreciate some help!

Comment: My approach to use auth/refresh tokens goes like this: I use an `AuthProvider` using react contexts that wraps the whole app and Auth Token will be stored there, user makes an auth request to server, server sets a http-only cookie containing refresh token. in auth Provider you send a request to `/user` for example, since `refreshToken` is present in the request, server will respond with an `AuthToken` and you set the `AuthToken` as a memory value which you can use to add to header of your furthur requests. i can provide an example if you want

Comment: This way you omit a lot of security issues because you don't have to store authToken in neither `localStorage` or cookies and the `refreshToken` is stored in a http-only cookie which is inaccessible with javascript

Comment: @Amin Why use react context when OP is already using redux (which uses react context behind the scenes)? The rest of the app will want to know wether the user is logged in or not. This means components will have to connect to both redux and the AuthProvider to function. I'd strongly advise against that.

Comment: Using Contexts for UI states (e.g logged in status, dark theme, ...) can help you avoid complexity of redux for such simple things and it is usually encouraged, Although using redux alongside with react context and hooks is totally fine

Comment: Except "logged in" is not UI state at all, that's a pretty existential global state for the entire app usually. "avoiding the complexity of redux for such simple things" makes no sense to me - someone building a redux app is assumed to be mastering the tool they're using. Why would they have to avoid the primary state management library? I'm not saying react context doesn't have its use cases, but I strongly disagree that it should be used for global logged in state throughout the app. What if a redux selector is based on logged in state? You'll combine that with useMemo() over and over?